# How to send tweet from Google Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, twitter

I am following [Google oAuth](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tut_oauth.html) tutorial. And I am having some trouble with authorizing user.

I am sending user to twitter for authorization. As this is chrome extension and there is no callback. I dont know how to send tweet on the behalf of that user. 
How I am doing things:

1. I have a background page that has the code of authorizing user from twitter. On the time when user install the extension, background page send that user to twitter for authorization. My authorization method is getting called with their call back. But dont know if I am having everything to make a tweet.
2. Now when user will click on extension icon, the popup.html will be appear. And on this page I want user to send a tweet. How?

Following is my code:

**manifest.json**

```
{
"name": "TweetChrome",
"version": "1.0",
"description": "Tweet from Chrome",
"browser_action": {
"default_icon": "images/share.png",
 "popup": "popup.html"
},
"permissions": [
 "tabs",
"http://ajax.googleapis.com",
"*://*.twitter.com/*",
 "clipboardWrite"
],
"options_page": "options.html",
"background_page": "background.html"  
 }
```

**background.html**
I am getting some html page markup in resp of callback method. I dont know what it is for?

```
var oauth = ChromeExOAuth.initBackgroundPage({
                      'request_url': 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token',
                      'authorize_url': 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize',
                      'access_url': 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token',
                      'consumer_key': 'key',
                      'consumer_secret': 'secret',
                      'scope': '',
                      'app_name': 'TweetChrome'
                    });

                oauth.authorize(onAuthorized);  

            function onAuthorized() {
              var url = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize';
                           /*as they are optional, i left empty*/
              var request = {
                'force_login': '',
                'screen_name': ''
              };
              oauth.sendSignedRequest(url, callback, request);
            };

            function callback(resp, xhr) { alert('it get called too'); };
```

**popup.html**
To tweet I am using a borrowed [twitter.js](https://github.com/abraham/omnitweet/blob/master/extension/javascript/twitter.js). I didn't wrote it.

```
           Twitter.verify_credentials({install: true});           
       Twitter.update("test");
```

My approach of oauth is right on having it in a background page? As my authorization is getting call how much far I am to make a tweet for a user?

Any help will be appreciated. I am hopeful to solve this issue to finish my extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to request `https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize` in `onAuthorized` - once you get to that function, you already have a key and the user has authenticated.

Try requesting `http://api.twitter.com/1/account/verify_credentials.json` in `onAuthorized` instead.  You should see a JSON response with the user's information.

Comment: When user will come for first time. He has to be authorize. After when user authorized, I guess i should use verify_credentials. And then I can update the the status. Is my this understanding is right? Second I have confusion in my callback method. I dont know what I am getting in it. It will access token that need to be saved but I dont know how to get them. Any pointer on it?

Comment: The library does all this for you.  You can just start making requests using `sendSignedRequest` and the library will handle signing, etc.